# Tidyverse/faster solution to conditional formatting with openxlsx in R?

Tags: r, excel, conditional-formatting, tidyverse, openxlsx

I'm working with genetic data that look like this table, but larger:

```
ID allele.a allele.b
A      115       90
A      115       90
A      116       90
B      120       82
B      120       82
B      120      82M
```

My goal is to highlight, for each ID, which alleles *don't* match the alleles listed on the *first* row of each ID group. I need to export the data to a nicely formatted excel file.

**Here's what I want:**

[image: Desired result]

I can get there with the following script, but the actual script involves about 67 "ID"s, 1000 rows of data, and 37 columns. It takes about 5 minutes to run, so I'm hoping to find a solution that significantly decreases processing time. Maybe a "do" solution from the tidyverse - not sure how that would look.

Here's my script, including a test data.frame. Also including a bigger test data.frame for speed testing.

```
library(xlsx)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

# Small data.frame
dframe <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                     allele.a = c("115", "115", "116", "120", "120", "120"),
                     allele.b = c("90", "90", "90", "82", "82", "82M"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

# Bigger data.frame for speed test
# dframe <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters, each = 30),
#                      allele.a = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 100, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.b = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 90, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.c = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 80, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.d = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 70, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.e = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 60, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.f = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 50, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.g = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 40, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.h = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 30, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.i = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 20, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      allele.j = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 10, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
#                      stringsAsFactors = F)



# Create a new excel workbook ----
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add a worksheets
addWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1, gridLines = TRUE)

# add the data to the worksheet        
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, dframe, rowNames = FALSE)      

# Create a style to show alleles that do not match the first row.
style_Red_NoMatch <- createStyle(fontColour = "#FFFFFF", # white text
                                 bgFill = "#CC0000", # Dark red background
                                 textDecoration = c("BOLD")) # bold text

Groups <- unique(dframe$ID)

start_time <- Sys.time()
# For each unique group, 
for(i in 1:length(Groups)){

  # Print a message telling us where the script is processing in the file.
  print(paste("Formatting unique group ", i, "/", length(Groups), sep = ""))

  # What are the allele values of the *first* individual in the group?
  Allele.values <- dframe %>% 
    filter(ID == Groups[i]) %>% 
    slice(1) %>% 
    select(2:ncol(dframe)) %>% 
    as.character()

  # for each column that has allele values in it,
  for (j in 1:length(Allele.values)){
    # format the rest of the rows so that a value that does not match the first value gets red style


    conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = 1, 
                          style_Red_NoMatch, 
                          rows = (which(dframe$ID == Groups[i]) + 1), 
                          cols = 1+j,  rule=paste("<>\"", Allele.values[j], "\"", sep = ""))
  }

}
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time

saveWorkbook(wb, "Example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way to improve is to apply `conditionalFormatting` on the entire column instead of having to loop through each cell.

Here is one way. One downside with this approach though is that it creates logical vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` which is used for `conditionalFormatting`. These columns can be hidden using `setColWidths` function.

**Data**

```
library(openxlsx)

 dframe <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters, each = 30),
                      allele.a = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 100, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.b = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 90, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.c = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 80, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.d = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 70, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.e = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 60, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.f = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 50, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.g = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 40, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.h = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 30, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.i = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 20, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      allele.j = rep(as.character(round(rnorm(n = 30, mean = 10, sd = 0.3), 0)), 26),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

First part of the script is unchanged.

```
# Create a new excel workbook ----
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add a worksheets
addWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1, gridLines = TRUE)
    
# Create a style to show alleles that do not match the first row.
style_Red_NoMatch <- createStyle(fontColour = "#FFFFFF", # white text
                                 bgFill = "#CC0000", # Dark red background
                                 textDecoration = c("BOLD")) # bold text
```

Then identify first row for each ID and merge into the original dataset. Then check to see if there are any changes in any cells (loops through each column).

```
# selects first row for each ID which will be used as benchmark
first_row <- dframe[!duplicated(dframe$ID), ]

# Creating new df with the first_row columns added
dframe_chk <- merge(dframe, first_row, by = "ID",  all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", "_first"))

# Adding TRUE/FALSE factor for each column to see if it matches or not (-1 to exclude ID column)
for (j in names(dframe)[-1]) {
  
  dframe_chk[, paste0(j, "_chk")] <- dframe_chk[, j] == dframe_chk[, paste0(j, "_first")]
  
}

# Remove _first columns when exporting into Excel
cols <- names(dframe_chk)[!grepl("_first", names(dframe_chk))]

# add the data to the worksheet        
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, dframe_chk[, cols], rowNames = FALSE)      

# This is for conditional Formatting
# first_row is header
row_start <- 2

# Need to add 1 to cover full range (as first row is header)
row_end <- nrow(dframe) + 1

# first column is ID
col_start <- 2 

# last column as per the original dataset
col_end <- ncol(dframe)

# this is to point to the _chk column.
# Note if you have columns more than A-Z then this needs to be adjusted
rule_col <- LETTERS[col_end + 1] 

# Using the _chk column to apply conditional formula
conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = 1, 
                      style_Red_NoMatch, 
                      rows = row_start:row_end,
                      cols = col_start:col_end,  
                      rule = paste0(rule_col, "2 = FALSE"))

# Exported file includes _chk columns. Hide these columns.
setColWidths(wb, sheet = 1, cols = (col_end + 1):length(cols), hidden = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "Example2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```